# Values in array of structs turning into garbage values

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an issue that's really confusing me... Below I am calling an initialize function:

```
void Initialize (List *L) {
    char* initialize = "initialize";
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<MAXLISTSIZE; i++) {
       strncpy(L->items[i].name,initialize,MAXNAMESIZE);
       L->items[i].name[MAXNAMESIZE - 1] = '\0';
       L->items[i].grade = 0;
       printf("L->items[i].name = %s\n", L->items[i].name);
       printf("L->items[i].grade = %d\n", L->items[i].grade);
    }    
    L->count = 0;
}
```

And it seems to work, I print the values in the loop and it's fine. If I also print inside an identical loop in main to double check it works as well but If I just print the values in main after the initialize function (no print statements in Initialize) I get complete garbage.

It seems the memory I'm storing my values in isn't staying consistent and I can't figure out why.

Do I need to malloc memory for the structs? Since I don't need a variable amount of storage I thought it was not necessary... I am unsure of how to go about that.

My Structs:

```
typedef Student Item;
#define MAXLISTSIZE 4
typedef struct {
Item items[MAXLISTSIZE];
int count;
} List;

#define MAXNAMESIZE 20
typedef struct {
char name[MAXNAMESIZE];
int grade;   
} Student;
```

I am simply calling Initialize from main:

```
int main () {
    List *newList;

    /*call initialize function*/
    newList = callInitialize();

return 0;
}
```

callInitialize:

```
List *callInitialize () {
List *L;

List studentList;
L = &studentList;

Initialize(L); 

return L;
}
```

Comment: What's `callInitialize` and what does it have to do with `Initialize`??? Where and how do you call `Initialize`?

Comment: 1) Always compile with all warnings. 2) Use valgrind or a similar memory debugger. Don't post until you've done both of those and come out clean, or do post the specific error or warnings that you get. The point is that if you do any amount of debugging work yourself, then you either discover the problem, or you'll be able to ask a specific question rather than dump your entire code and say "this doesn't work".

Comment: @Kerrek-SB I'm sorry I was missing a function and added that. I realize I can't expect to post my code and say fix it, this is not my whole code but everything I thought that was important to my question, I don't get any compiler warnings. I have spent a long time trying to get it working myself but haven't been able to come up with a solution. I am not a very experienced programmer and have never used a memory debugger but I will look into that. Sorry again, and thank you for your time.

Comment: @cdn88: No worries! What's your compiler? I'm not sure if you'd get a warning, since this is somewhat hard to detect statically. However, whenever you see any sort of "garbled output", you should definitely check out a memory debugger. On Linux, `valgrind` is extremely easy to use and exceedingly helpful. (Compile with debug symbols for best results.) I'm sure others can suggest memory debuggers for Windows and MacOS.

Comment: @Kerrek-SB: I am using gcc with these (-Wall -ansi -pedantic -g) compiler arguments. I am definitely going to check out valgrind! I wish I would have learned about that earlier. Thank you!

Comment: @cdn88: With GCC, I usually use `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, but it looks like you're in good shape. Sometimes you get useful warnings like "variable so-and-so may be used uninitialized", and I'm pretty surprised that you're not getting a "returning pointer to local variable" warning, but some things don't get noticed by the compiler...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you posted the function that causes the actual problem, we see what's wrong: You are returning the address of a local variable that goes out of scope! This is not valid.

```
List * foo()
{
  List x;     // <--- x comes to life
  return &x;  // <--- x dies here...
}

int main()
{
  List * p = foo();  // ... but its address is used here!
  p->name ...        // dereferencing an invalid address!!
}
```

Your situation calls for *dynamic* (or "manual") allocation, which means memory allocation whose lifetime is controlled only by *you*, and not by the local scope.

```
List * initList()
{
  return malloc(sizeof(List)); // this memory is permanent
}
```

Any manual allocation needs to come with a clean-up routine:

```
void freeList(List * p)
{
  free(p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was neglecting the scope of List *L! And I am really sorry for making the mistake in my post and wasting peoples time. Take care.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best :-)

Answer (score 4):

Now that you've posted the remainder of your code, the problem is obvious:

```
List *callInitialize () {
    List *L;

    List studentList;
    L = &studentList;

    Initialize(L); 

    return L;
}
```

Within this function you create a local variable `studentList` which you the pass to `Initialize` to set it up.

Unfortunately, the scope of the `studentList` variable ends when you exit the `callInitialize` function. That's why it may contain rubbish when you attempt to use it later on.

Despite your comment about not needing `malloc` because the structure is small, you *do* need it if you want the scope of the data to exist beyond the function it's created in.

Probably the "minimal-change" solution would be:

```
List *callInitialize (void) {
    List *L = malloc (sizeof (List));
    if (L != NULL)
        Initialize(&L); 
    return L;
}
```

and then remember that it needs to be freed at some point by the caller, unless the `malloc` fails and this function therefore returns NULL.

Comment: I am very sorry I forgot the function callInitialize I added it to the post. I didn't think I would need malloc because my struct items are a set size and not very large.